# How can I use a CSS selector to find a custom button in Orbeon 2016.1?

Tags: orbeon

Using Orbeon 4.10 if I defined a button like this:

```
<property 
    as="xs:string" 
    name="oxf.fr.resource.*.*.en.buttons.send-to-service" 
    value="Send"/>
```

the button would then be surrounded by a `span` with this CSS class: `fr-send-to-service-button`.

I am using the Orbeon Proxy Portlet in conjunction with custom portlets that wrap the Orbeon functionality. Previously it was very easy to hide the button with CSS and simulate clicking on it with JavaScript. But now there is no CSS class that I can use to find the button.

Was this CSS class intentionally removed in Orbeon 2016.1? Is there a way I can specify CSS for the button? Or is there some other way I can identify the button?

I need to be able to:

1. Hide it with CSS
2. Simulate clicking on it, for example, `$('.fr-send-to-service-button').click()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was not intentional, and it is already fixed for 2016.2 ([issue #2739](https://github.com/orbeon/orbeon-forms/issues/2739)). In 2016.1.0, unfortunately, there is no CSS class.